# Graphics card replacement?

Tags: graphics-card

I have this computer.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007BZPRYG/ref=oh_details_o09_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007BZPRYG)

I am trying to find out what kind of, if any, graphics card can I purchase to replace the old one without having to change much inside.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from the Amazon page what expansion slots the motherboard has. It looks like it using an HD 6450 graphics card (here's a [review](http://techreport.com/review/20728/amd-radeon-hd-6450-graphics-card)) which uses a [PCI-Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) expansion slots. You should be able to buy a more powerful graphics card to upgrade it (but as OCDtech points out not too powerful without also upgrading your power supply)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCI-Express video cards with that system.  There's no question you have a PCI-E slot for video.  The AMD HD6450 in your machine right now is available only in a discreet PCI-E form.  Due to the power supply in that machine I'd avoid video cards with a very high power draw, but most PCI-E video cards should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card is a Radeon HD 6450, PCIe x16 hi-def (3D capable) graphics card, 750 MHz GPU with 1GB of VRAM. If you want to go shopping on your own this is the info you'll need to compare (there's more to it, but that should be enough to find one that's similar or better).

Since you asked for a recommendation...I have always been delighted with GE Force and NVIDIA, so I would suggest a [GTX 650 Ti](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650ti). Decent price, great graphics.